# Multiple Immutable Id's for same mail message?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an Office Outlook add-in that has a React frontend and a dotnet core backend. I have set up a subscription using the Graph API to receive notifications when a new email appears on the SentItems folder. I want to correlate the email from the notification with information I have stored in a database.

Unfortunately the item id changes when the email is sent and moves from the Drafts folder into SentItems so it isn't useful for matching.

There is a new ImmutableId that doesn't change when the email is moved between folders. I've been unable to get the Office.js lib to generate an ImmutableId but there is a [translateExchangeIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method that when given an email item id will return an immutable id.

```
// convert to immutable
var translateRequest = new {
    inputIds = new string [] { mailMessage.ItemId },
    targetIdType = "restImmutableEntryId",
    sourceIdType = "restId"
};
var immutableResponse = await graphClient.PostAsJsonAsync("me/translateExchangeIds", translateRequest);
var immutableId = await immutableResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I can use that immutable id to retrieve the email message using the Graph request:

```
await graphClient.GetAsync($"Users/cccccccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-ba0c52e56d99/Messages/AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AQ-irLc2NFESKcGAhz1k_GBBDB5JMOwAA/
```

But the immutable id that is returned with the subscription notification is a different immutable id for the same message. So it's not possible to match the notification mail message with the message info stored in my database. So I still have to attach a custom property to the message for the sole purpose of matching the database entry with the SentItems notification.

Is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Update: my theory is the difference occurs because the immutable id is derived when the item is in different folders? When translating the item id to an immutable id, the item is still in the Drafts folder. When the subscription notification occurs, the item is in the Sent Items folder. The following responses were from queries using the different immutable id's but identify the same message - the `myId` GUID is a custom property attached to the message and used to correlate the notification with the message info stored in a local database.

```
\"id\":\"AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AQ-irLc2NFESKcGAhz1k_GAADB4INPAAA\",...,\"myId\":\"8baa904f-cf64-437c-878c-be4f71714aee\"

\"id\":\"AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AQ-irLc2NFESKcGAhz1k_GAADB4INLwAA\",...,\"myId\":\"8baa904f-cf64-437c-878c-be4f71714aee\"
```

Comment: Can you share the id that you've received as a part of the notification? Are you converting the same using translateExchangeIds api?

Comment: @Sivaprakash see update

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this and now you should see the same ImmutableId for draft and sent messages. Can you try and let us know if this is working as expected?

Comment: But both immutable id's refer to the same message, correct? I can use either immutable id to retrieve the message using the Graph API.

Comment: No, the messages are distinct.

Comment: So are you suggesting that the translated immutable id from the draft id is pointing to a different but identical message to the immutable id from the subscription notification?